# Connecting to IRC Server C++ Windows 10 Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, irc

So I am fairly new to C++/C and only learned the language about a week ago so I'm a bit lost. I am trying to build an IRC Client to connect to a server and I can't seem to get it to work. I am using Visual Studio as my IDE and have followed the instructions listed on here for Socket connections: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/complete-client-code

```
// Testing.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

void SendData(string s) {
    if (send(ConnectSocket, s.c_str(), sizeof(s.c_str()), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cout << "send failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
    }
    else { cout << s << endl; }
}

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;

    // Initialize Winsock
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData)) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed");
        system("pause");
    }
    else { cout << "WinSock Started" << endl; }

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
        *ptr = NULL,
        hints;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port

    if (getaddrinfo("38.229.70.22", "6665", &hints, &result)) {
        cout << "GetAddrInfo FAILED" << endl;
        WSACleanup();
        system("pause");
    }

    // Attempt to connect to the first address returned by
    // the call to getaddrinfo
    ptr = result;

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,
        ptr->ai_protocol);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        cout << "Error at socket(): " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        system("pause");
    }

    // Connect to server.
    if (connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    // Should really try the next address returned by getaddrinfo
    // if the connect call failed
    // But for this simple example we just free the resources
    // returned by getaddrinfo and print an error message

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        cout << "Unable to connect to server!\n" << endl;
        WSACleanup();
        system("pause");
    }
    else { cout << "CONNECTED!!!" << endl; }

    string pass = "PASS none\r\n", nick = "NICK TestUserFoo\r\n", user = "USER guest 0 * :TestUserFoo\r\n", join = "JOIN #etc";
    SendData(pass);
    SendData(nick);
    SendData(user);
    SendData(join);

    char recvbuf[512];

    int iResult;

    cout << "Data Sent" << endl;

    // shutdown the connection for sending since no more data will be sent
    // the client can still use the ConnectSocket for receiving data
    /*iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }*/

    // Receive data until the server closes the connection
    do {
        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf), 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
            cout << "Bytes received: " << iResult << endl << recvbuf << endl;
        else if (iResult == 0)
            cout << "Connection closed\n";
        else
            cout << "recv failed: " << WSAGetLastError() <<endl;
    } while (iResult > 0);

    system("pause");
}
```

I decided to connect to an empty channel on freenode and got the ip of chat.freenode.net by doing a ping-ing it. When I connect, here is my output:

```
WinSock Started
CONNECTED!!!
PASS none

NICK TestUserFoo

USER guest 0 * :TestUserFoo

JOIN #etc
Data Sent
Bytes received: 62
:card.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** Looking up your hostname...
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╚Σv
Bytes received: 103
:card.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** Checking Ident
:card.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** Found your hostname
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╚Σv
```

It seems my commands sent for PASS NICK and USER aren't being interpreted or properly sent to the IRC server since I'm not getting a response back. What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
sizeof(s.c_str())
```

in

```
if (send(ConnectSocket, s.c_str(), sizeof(s.c_str()), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
```

The `sizeof` operator is returning the size of the `char*` (which may be 4 bytes or 8 bytes depending if it's a 32-bit or 64-bit application).

You want to change it to:

```
if (send(ConnectSocket, s.c_str(), s.size(), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
```